# Regex expression with "&nbsp" glued to content

Tags: php, regex

I'm have trouble with a regular expression while I'm trying to capture some data in this HTML:

```
<ul>
       <li>Nombre de mots à traduire&nbsp;:&nbsp;41 mots.</li>
       <li>Nombre de mots partiellement traduits&nbsp;:&nbsp;164 mots.</li>
       <li>Nombre de mots traduits&nbsp;:&nbsp;792 mots.</li>
       <li>Nombre de correspondances exactes&nbsp;:&nbsp;808 mots.</li>
       <li>Nombre de répétitions internes&nbsp;:&nbsp;71 mots.</li>
       <li>Total&nbsp;:&nbsp;1876 mots.</li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the quantity of 'mots' for every `<li>` in PHP Regex, but the `&nbsp;:&nbsp;` it's glued to the number and I can't get it.

I'm trying to use on the first one `(?<=\btraduire&nbsp;:&nbsp;\s)(\w+)` but it doesn't make sense... I can't modify the HTML in any way, and I can't use `html_entity_decode()`.

This HTML changes dynamically, I mean the length of this numbers will change, it's just one example.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: 
Okay with `(\d+)\smots` I can get it!! =D But if I have:

```
<p>
    Langue source&nbsp;:&nbsp;FRA (FRA)<br/>
    Langue cible&nbsp;:&nbsp;ESP (ESP)
</p>
```

And I want to get the "FRA (FRA)" and "ESP (ESP)", any idea?

Comment: Use a DOM parser and then you don't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the quantity of `mots` for each `<li>` you should probably use a Regex like this:

```
(\d+)\smots
```

But note however that if you're trying to parse HTML you're probably better off using an HTML parser as regular expressions have a hard time with non-regular syntax (i.e. HTML, XML)

**UPDATE**

For your second query, I would try something like this:

```
Langue.*([A-Z]{3})\s\(\1\)
```

In the above, the first capture group should be the language. The `\1` in the last part of the regex refers to the first capture group which means that `FRA (FRA)` would match, but `FRA (BLA)` would not.

Comment: It works, thank you! I edited the question, you know how to do this other? And what's the advantage of use a HTML parser?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
preg_match_all('~[0-9]+(?= mots.</li>)~', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

or more explicit:

```
preg_match_all('~(?J)<li>(?:Nombre de (?<what>[^&]++)|(?<what>Total))[^0-9]+(?<quantity>[0-9]+)[^<]*</li>~i', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

For your edit:

```
preg_match_all('~Langue (?<target>[^&\s]++);:&nbsp;\s*(?<language>[^\r\n<]+)\s*~i', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    printf("\n%s\t%s", $match['target'], $match['language']);
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you! it's a good trick to use mots. I edited the question, you know how to do this other?